# In Solr, what is the difference between the NOT and - (minus) operators?

Tags: lucene, solr, operators

In Solr, is there a difference between the NOT and - (minus) operators?  If so, what is it?

Solr documentation references the [Lucene Query Parser Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#NOT), and it is vague on this matter.  The two operators seem to function the same way, but it's not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on Mauricio's answer (because the QueryParser class is some of the most confusing code I've ever read) if you look at lines 145-152 you'll see:

```
  case MINUS:
    jj_consume_token(MINUS);
             ret = MOD_NOT;
    break;
  case NOT:
    jj_consume_token(NOT);
           ret = MOD_NOT;
    break;
```

So they are both considered `MOD_NOT`s.

Answer (score 3):

The [Lucene QueryParser code says they're equivalent](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/2ca648abce9363f827e2a8fff2815fc8f3abadd5/lucene/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.java#L145).